# Summing opposite directional vectors of a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, apply

I have a matrix, for example:

```
mat <- matrix(sample.int(100,100),10,10)
```

Each vector of the matrix represents the number of times an event occured between two parties. For example, mat[1,2] is how many times 1 did X to 2. I want to find the pair that has had the most interactions. In other words, I want to determine the values of x and y where the following function is maximized:

```
mat[x,y]+mat[y,x]
```

OR

```
mat[x,y]+t(mat)[x,y]
```

Then, if possible I would like to do this for 3 variables: x,y,z. Aka, finding the values for x,y,z that maximizes:

```
mat[x,y]+mat[y,x]+mat[x,z]+mat[y,z]+mat[z,y]+mat[z,x]
```

What would be the best way to do this? I figure some sort of apply function would work best but I am struggling with a potential solution. Thank you!

Comment: You probably should look into using igraph to analyze your weighted directed graph.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the index number of the rows and columns fulfilling this criterion you can use

```
arrayInd(which.max(mat + t(mat)), dim(mat))
```

Another option would be

```
which((mat + t(mat)) == max(mat + t(mat)), arr.ind=TRUE)
```